# How does GFP_ATOMIC prevent sleep

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How does GFP_ATOMIC ( in kzalloc) prevent sleep?

Also found

```
#define GFP_ATOMIC (__GFP_HIGH)
```

However did not understand furhter..?

Answer (score 3):

`GFP_ATOMIC` prevents sleeping by telling the memory allocation code that it's not allowed to sleep to satisfy the allocation - that's all.  If the memory allocation code needs to sleep, and `GFP_ATOMIC` has been passed, then it will return an error to the caller instead.

Answer (score 3):

if you try to allocate the memory in the linux kernel then it could be done with the help of function named kmalloc(size,flags).
But the **flag parameter in the function is basically instruct the kernel how the memory should be allocated. there are basically three zones of flags as action modifiers, zone modifiers and types**.

If u give the flag as **GFP_ATOMIC then the allocation is high-priority and does not sleep. This is the flag to use in interrupt handlers, bottom halves and other situations where you cannot sleep.**

& **it is done basically instructing the kernel to get the memory chunks from the pre-allocated slab memory if there is memory in the slab then it is allocated atomically else allocation fails**.

For more info http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6930

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to `GFP_ATOMIC` is `GFP_KERNEL`:
`#define GFP_KERNEL (__GFP_WAIT | __GFP_IO | __GFP_FS)`.

`GFP_KERNEL` incldes `__GFP_WAIT`, which is tested in various situations where sleep is considered. Without this flag, there's no sleep.